# Cross-module variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

this question might have been asked already but all I find are specific case and I can't find a way to use the answers to solve my own problem.

What I want is a variable than has a single instance and is shared between modules/files

Let's say I have app.js and module.js

app.js:

```
var mymodule = require('./modules/mymodule.js');
var testVar = 'test';

...
```

mymodule.js:

```
var mymodule = {count:0}
var logCount = function() {console.log(mymodule.count);}

module.exports = mymodule;
```

Then with this code when app execute `mymodule.count = 1`, if after mymodules.js run `logCount()` it will log 1, this means that app and mymodule are sharing the exact same instance of `mymodule.count`

Now how can mymodule.js access to the same instance as testVar used by app.js in a way that if app.js change it's value, mymodule will have the same new value.

For exemple in normal javascript, if you include two scripts in an html page, as long as the variable isn't inside a function, every javascript file can access the variable, because it works as if all the script would have been pasted inside a single file, isn't there a way to obtain the same result in node?

Comment: What you are trying to do will pretty likely lead to a cyclic dependency between the two modules. You should try to avoid this, since it may cause unnecessary headache down the line. If this seems like a reasonable requirement nonetheless, that's often a sign that the code should really be a single module, not two.

Comment: I'm not sure, I have a main app that is a bot, his goal is to treat much much data, all the data are stored in an array 'datas' inside app.js, each time a new data is coming, app.js push it to 'datas' and ask mymodule to scan it, based on datas, and data (eg. mymodule.scan(datas, data)) to scan data object inside datas array, but datas is very large (1go++) and it would be way easier if scanning module could access it directly instead of 'recieving' it from app.js